# Show Product Version column with the msi file in windows explorer

Tags: c#, winforms, wix, windows-installer, version

I have an msi which is developed using wix.
CustomAction in wix project triggers a Winform UI.

```
<Product Id="*" Name="App" Language="1033" Codepage="UTF-8" Version="10.10.10.10" Manufacturer="Corporation" UpgradeCode="{Your app Upgrade code}">
```

So in C# winform, i am able to get the ProductVersion (from above code in wix project .wxs file) in winform.
I want to know that how can i show that product version with the msi file in Windows Explorer.
Please help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to see the ProductVersion only for yourself or do you want users to see the ProductVersion? In the former case you might find a shell extension that can show Windows Installer properties. You could also open the .msi file in a tool like Orca or InstEd and have a look at the Property table.

Comment: Good question. Do you want to see this on your own machine or for users to see it on all of their machines?  I wouldn't write a shell extension for the latter and for the former it hardly seems worth the effort to me as @zett42 points out you can just look at it in Orca.

Answer (score 5):

Windows Explorer can only see attributes in the [Summary Information Stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372044(v=vs.85).aspx).  ProductVersion is in the Property table.  The best you could do is append (duplicate) the product version in one of the Summary Information Stream attributes  such as Product Name or Description.

Comment: You took the question in a different way.
First of all i want all users to see the ProductVersion, though they can see it using Orca but then they have to download Orca separately, but i want to show the ProductVersion with the msi file itself like it shows type, size in windows explorer like this:-

'Name          Type                                         Size               ProductVersion
Msi File       Windows Installer Package      322,22,22'

So here with this file,  i want to show the productversion also

Comment: I took it a different way because what you ask isn't supported or possible.